# Change css class on the fly with a button press (while pulling class names from an array).

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, button, counter

How to change css class on the fly with a button press (while pulling class names from an array).  If I hard code the classes into a switch statement, I can step through the classes fine.  But, when I try and pull class names from an array, it jumps to the end of switch statement. I believe that I need to have the button press halt the counter for the array, so I can step through.  The 'Switch Class' and 'array switch' buttons are the ones that I am working with here.

The switch which works (the 'Switch Class button:

```
  <script>
  var clcks = 1;

    $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#swtchClss").click(function(){

                    if (clcks < 8){

                    clcks+=1;

                        }
                            else{

                            clcks = 1;

                        }
                                switch (true) {
            case clcks == 1:
                $('#txtbox6').addClass('ordrTabl1');
                $('#txtbox6').removeClass('ordrTabl8');
                break;                  
            case clcks == 2:
                $('#txtbox6').addClass('ordrTabl2');
                $('#txtbox6').removeClass('ordrTabl1');
                break;
            case clcks == 3:
                $('#txtbox6').addClass('ordrTabl3');
                $('#txtbox6').removeClass('ordrTabl2');
                break;
            case clcks == 4:
                $('#txtbox6').addClass('ordrTabl4');
                $('#txtbox6').removeClass('ordrTabl3');
                break; 
            case clcks == 5:
                $('#txtbox6').addClass('ordrTabl5');
                $('#txtbox6').removeClass('ordrTabl4');
                break; 
            case clcks == 6:
                $('#txtbox6').addClass('ordrTabl6');
                $('#txtbox6').removeClass('ordrTabl5');
                break; 
            case clcks == 7:
                $('#txtbox6').addClass('ordrTabl7');
                $('#txtbox6').removeClass('ordrTabl6');
                break; 
            case clcks == 8:
                $('#txtbox6').addClass('ordrTabl8');
                $('#txtbox6').removeClass('ordrTabl7');
                break; 
                                }
    });
    });
</script>
```

The switch with the array that is giving me trouble (the 'array switch' button.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {   
    $('#cyclStylsArrayCntr').click(function(event){
    var curClass = ['ordrTabl1', 'ordrTabl2', 'ordrTabl3', 'ordrTabl4',  'ordrTabl5', 'ordrTabl6', 'ordrTabl7', 'ordrTabl8'];      
 // Array of scores
    var arrayLength = curClass.length;// Items in array
    var clcks = 0;            // Current round
    var msg = '';                   // Message

    // Loop through the items in the array
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {

      // Arrays are zero based (so 0 is round 1)
      // Add 1 to the current round
      clcks = (i + 1);

                                switch (true) {
            case clcks == 1:
            alert (clcks);
                $('#txtbox6').addClass(curClass[i]);
                $('#txtbox6').removeClass('ordrTabl8');
                break;                  
            case clcks == 2:
                $('#txtbox6').addClass(curClass[i]);
                $('#txtbox6').removeClass('ordrTabl1');
                break;
            case clcks == 3:
                $('#txtbox6').addClass(curClass[i]);
                $('#txtbox6').removeClass('ordrTabl2');
                break;
            case clcks == 4:
                $('#txtbox6').addClass('ordrTabl4');
                $('#txtbox6').removeClass('ordrTabl3');
                break; 
            case clcks == 5:
                $('#txtbox6').addClass('ordrTabl5');
                $('#txtbox6').removeClass('ordrTabl4');
                break; 
            case clcks == 6:
                $('#txtbox6').addClass('ordrTabl6');
                $('#txtbox6').removeClass('ordrTabl5');
                break; 
            case clcks == 7:
                $('#txtbox6').addClass('ordrTabl7');
                $('#txtbox6').removeClass('ordrTabl6');
                break; 
            case clcks == 8:
            alert (clcks);
                $('#txtbox6').addClass('ordrTabl8');
                $('#txtbox6').removeClass('ordrTabl7');
                break; 
                                }
    }   

 } );

    }); 

 </script>
```

The HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 

<html> 

<head> 
<title> Order Entry  </title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css"> 
<script src="js/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/popUpBtns.js"></script>
<script src="js/toggleBtns.js"></script>
<script src="js/SwitchClass.js"></script>
<script src="js/arrayCountrSwtch.js"></script>
<!--    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/popUps.css">  -->
    <style>
.detail {
padding: 5px; 

}
.tmp9   {
position:absolute;
top:100px;
right:100px;
}
.ordrTabl1  {
    height:800px;
width:800px;
border:2px solid #340909;
background-color:#474545;
margin:auto;
padding:15px;
}
.ordrTabl2  {
    height:800px;
width:800px;
border:6px double #696969;
background-color:#ff9999;
margin:auto;
padding:15px;
box-shadow:2px 2px 2px #FF9999, 10px 10px 2px #333333;
}
.ordrTabl3  {
    height:800px;
width:800px;
border:6px double #CD5C5C;
background-color:#80dfff;
margin:auto;
padding:15px;
box-shadow:2px 2px 2px #CD5C5C, 10px 10px 2px #333333;
}
.ordrTabl4  {
    height:800px;
width:800px;
border:6px double #CD5C5C;
background-color:#708090;
margin:auto;
padding:15px;
box-shadow:10px 10px 2px #333333;
}
.ordrTabl5  {
    height:800px;
width:800px;
border:6px double #CD5C5C;
background-color:white;
margin:auto;
padding:15px;
box-shadow:10px 10px 2px #333333;
}
.ordrTabl6  {
    height:800px;
width:800px;
border:6px double #CD5C5C;
background-color:aqua;
margin:auto;
padding:15px;
box-shadow:10px 10px 2px #333333;
}
.ordrTabl7  {
    height:800px;
width:800px;
border:6px double #CD5C5C;
background-color:brown;
margin:auto;
padding:15px;
box-shadow:10px 10px 2px #333333;
}
.ordrTabl8  {
    height:800px;
width:800px;
border:6px double #CD5C5C;
background-color:magenta;
margin:auto;
padding:15px;
box-shadow:10px 10px 2px #333333;
}
#ordr       {

}       
    </style>

</head> 
<body> 
<header  role="banner"><h1> xxx </h1></header>
  <h2></h2> 
         <button id="swapStyle1">swapStyle1 </button>
        <button id="swapStyle2">swapStyle2 </button>
        <button id="swapStyle3">swapStyle3 </button>
        <button id="cyclStyls">Cycle through styles</button>
        <button id="one" value="1" 
        OnClick="cyclStylsSwtch()">Select</button>
        <button id="cyclStylsSwtch">Cycle through styles</button>
        <button id="cyclStylsArrayCntr">array switch</button>
        <button id="swtchClss">swtchClss</button>
  <h1>Order</h1>
            <p> Order Form</p>

        <div id="txtbox6" class="ordrTabl1">

        <h1>Order</h1>
            <p> Order Form</p>

                <form name="contactForm" id="prdcts">

                <table border=15>

                <tr>
                <td width=150>Item<br>
                &nbsp;</td>
                <td width=25>Price<br>
                &nbsp;</td>
                <td width=15>Quantity<br>
                &nbsp;</td>

                </tr>
                <tr>

                <td>Smoked Ham</td>
                <td>$3.00 lb</td>

                <td align="center"><input type="number" name="ham" 
                id="ham" value="0" size="3" maxlength="3"></td>

                </tr>

                <tr>
                <td>Smoked Herring </td>
                <td>$1.00 oz</td>

                <td align="center"><input type="number" name="herring" 
      id="herring" value="0" size="3" maxlength="3"></td>

                </tr>

                <tr>
                <td>Texas Hotlinks</td>
                <td>$2.00 each</td>

                <td align="center"><input type="number" value="0" 
   name="htlnk" id="htlnk" size="3" 
                maxlength="3"></td>

                </tr>



                <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center"><br>
                <h4> Buttons located here clear screen data </h4>

                </td>
                <td align="center"><input type="reset" value="Clear  
                Form" onclick="clearForm()"></td>
                </tr>
                </table>

                </form>
                <button id="pop7">Display Form data Products sold 
                 </button>
                <button id="clrSaleData">clear Sales Data Pop Up</button>
                </div>

                <p class="tmp" style="display:none;"></p>





                <div class="tmp9"></div>






  <article class="focal">



    </article>

    <aside role="complementary" class="sidebar">





    </aside>



</section> 

<footer role="contentinfo">         </footer> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Additional scripts needed to run the HTML as is:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
$("#pop7").click(function(){
    var hamPrice=3;
    var herringPrice=1;
    var linkPrice=3;
    var ham=document.getElementById('ham').value;
    var herring=document.getElementById('herring').value;
    var htlnk=document.getElementById('htlnk').value;
    var divObj=document.getElementById("txtbox4");
    var hamTotal = hamPrice*ham;
    var herringTotal = herringPrice*herring;
    var linkTotal = linkPrice*htlnk;
    var grandTotal = hamTotal + herringTotal + linkTotal;
    $('.tmp9').css("background-color", "#75BDFF");
    $('.tmp9').css("height", "400px");
    $('.tmp9').css("width", "400px");
    $('.tmp9').css("box-shadow", "10px 10px 2px #333333");
    $('.tmp9').css("border", " 6px double  #660000");
    $('.tmp9').css("-webkit-border-radius", "9px");
    $('.tmp9').css("-moz-border-radius", "9px");
    $('.tmp9').css("border-radius", "9px");
    $('.tmp9').css("padding", "10px");
    $(".tmp9").toggle();  
    $(".tmp9").html('<p class="tmp9"><p>' + ham + ' hams sold at $' + 
hamPrice + ' for  $' +  hamTotal + '</p><br><p>' + herring + ' herring 
sold at $' + herringPrice + ' for  $' +  herringTotal + '</p><br><p>' + 
htlnk + ' Texas hot links sold at $' + linkPrice + ' for  $' +  
linkTotal + '</p><br><p > For a total sale of  $' + grandTotal +  
'</p><br> Thank you for your business.  Please come again. </p><br>');

     });
  });

    $(document).ready(function(){
$("#popup7").click(function(){
    $("#detail7").toggle();
    $(window.location.href ="#top")
});  });

    $(document).ready(function() {   
$('#swapStyle1').click(function(event){
  $('#txtbox6').addClass('ordrTabl1');
  $('#txtbox6').removeClass('ordrTabl2');
  $('#txtbox6').removeClass('ordrTabl3');
});
    }); 

    $(document).ready(function() {   
 $('#swapStyle2').click(function(event){
   $('#txtbox6').addClass('ordrTabl2');
  $('#txtbox6').removeClass('ordrTabl3');
  $('#txtbox6').removeClass('ordrTabl1');
  } );
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {   
$('#swapStyle3').click(function(event){
  $('#txtbox6').addClass('ordrTabl3');
  $('#txtbox6').removeClass('ordrTabl2');
  $('#txtbox6').removeClass('ordrTabl1');
} );
    }); 


    $(document).ready(function(){
$("#clrSaleData").click(function(){
    $('.tmp9').css("display", "none");
     });
});

    $(document).ready(function() {   
    $('#cyclStyls').click(function(event){
    var curClass = ['ordrTabl1', 'ordrTabl2', 'ordrTabl3'];     
    // Array of scores
    var arrayLength = curClass.length;// Items in array
    var count = 0;            // Current round
    var msg = '';                   // Message

    // Loop through the items in the array
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        $('#txtbox6').removeClass(curClass[i]);
      // Arrays are zero based (so 0 is round 1)
      // Add 1 to the current round
      count = (i + 1);
        alert (curClass[i])
         $('#txtbox6').addClass(curClass[i]);
    }   

} );

    }); 

    var cliks = 1;
    function cyclStylsSwtch(){

            if (cliks < 3){
                        cliks+=1;
                        }
                            else{
                            alert ('else statement')
                            cliks=1;
                        }
                                switch (true) {
            case cliks == 1:
                $('#txtbox6').addClass('ordrTabl1');
                $('#txtbox6').removeClass('ordrTabl3');
                break;                  
            case cliks == 2:
                $('#txtbox6').addClass('ordrTabl2');
                $('#txtbox6').removeClass('ordrTabl1');         
                break;
            case cliks == 3:
                $('#txtbox6').addClass('ordrTabl3');
                $('#txtbox6').removeClass('ordrTabl2');
                break;
            case cliks == 4:
                cliks=1;
                alert (cliks);
                break; 
            case cliks == 5:
            cliks=1;
                alert (cliks);
                break; 
                                }

    };

    $(document).ready(function(){
    var clix = 1;
  $("#cyclStylsSwtch").click(function(){

            if (clix < 8){
                        clix+=1;
                        }
                            else{
                            clix=1;
                        }
                                switch (true) {
            case clix == 1:
                $('#txtbox6').addClass('ordrTabl1');
                $('#txtbox6').removeClass('ordrTabl8');
                break;                  
            case clix == 2:
                $('#txtbox6').addClass('ordrTabl2');
                $('#txtbox6').removeClass('ordrTabl1');         
                break;
            case clix == 3:
                $('#txtbox6').addClass('ordrTabl3');
                $('#txtbox6').removeClass('ordrTabl2');
                break;
            case clix == 4:
                $('#txtbox6').addClass('ordrTabl4');
                $('#txtbox6').removeClass('ordrTabl3');
                break; 
            case clix == 5:
            $('#txtbox6').addClass('ordrTabl5');
                $('#txtbox6').removeClass('ordrTabl4');
                break;
            case clix == 6:
            $('#txtbox6').addClass('ordrTabl6');
                $('#txtbox6').removeClass('ordrTabl5');
                break; 
            case clix == 7:
            $('#txtbox6').addClass('ordrTabl7');
                $('#txtbox6').removeClass('ordrTabl6');
                break; 
            case clix == 8:
            $('#txtbox6').addClass('ordrTabl8');
                $('#txtbox6').removeClass('ordrTabl7');
                break; 
                                }



     });
 });
    </script>
```

Comment: I would imagine that 95% of this code is not relevant to your question.  Please create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 0):

**But, when I try and pull class names from an array, it jumps to the end of switch statement.**

you have placed your switch inside a loop and it goes for every value from 1 to 8 as far as i understand you logic when one switch operates then previous switch classes are removed and so the loop reaches at `clck = 8` and executes and gets out of the for  loop and all you see is 8th switch classes

take a look for javascript below it runs for case 1 and alert 1 and also for case 8.

I think you need to update your logic

```js
$(document).ready(function() {  
  
    $('#cyclStylsArrayCntr').click(function(event){
    var curClass = ['ordrTabl1', 'ordrTabl2', 'ordrTabl3', 'ordrTabl4',  'ordrTabl5', 'ordrTabl6', 'ordrTabl7', 'ordrTabl8'];      
 // Array of scores
    var arrayLength = curClass.length;// Items in array
    var clcks = 0;            // Current round
    var msg = '';                   // Message

    // Loop through the items in the array
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {

      // Arrays are zero based (so 0 is round 1)
      // Add 1 to the current round
      clcks = (i + 1);

                                switch (true) {
            case clcks == 1:
            alert (clcks);
                $('#txtbox6').addClass(curClass[i]);
                $('#txtbox6').removeClass('ordrTabl8');
                break;                  
            case clcks == 2:
                alert (clcks);
                $('#txtbox6').addClass(curClass[i]);
                $('#txtbox6').removeClass('ordrTabl1');
                break;
            case clcks == 3:
                alert (clcks);
                $('#txtbox6').addClass(curClass[i]);
                $('#txtbox6').removeClass('ordrTabl2');
                break;
            case clcks == 4:
                alert (clcks);
                $('#txtbox6').addClass('ordrTabl4');
                $('#txtbox6').removeClass('ordrTabl3');
                break; 
            case clcks == 5:
                alert (clcks);
                $('#txtbox6').addClass('ordrTabl5');
                $('#txtbox6').removeClass('ordrTabl4');
                break; 
            case clcks == 6:
                alert (clcks);
                $('#txtbox6').addClass('ordrTabl6');
                $('#txtbox6').removeClass('ordrTabl5');
                break; 
            case clcks == 7:
                alert (clcks);
                $('#txtbox6').addClass('ordrTabl7');
                $('#txtbox6').removeClass('ordrTabl6');
                break; 
            case clcks == 8:
            alert (clcks);
                $('#txtbox6').addClass('ordrTabl8');
                $('#txtbox6').removeClass('ordrTabl7');
                break; 
                                }
    }   

 } );

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cyclStylsArrayCntr">dfgdfgdfgdfg</div>
```

**I think you should remove for loop**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {  
   var clcks = 0; 
    $('#cyclStylsArrayCntr').click(function(event){
    var curClass = ['ordrTabl1', 'ordrTabl2', 'ordrTabl3', 'ordrTabl4',  'ordrTabl5', 'ordrTabl6', 'ordrTabl7', 'ordrTabl8'];      

    var msg = '';                   // Message

      // Arrays are zero based (so 0 is round 1)
      // Add 1 to the current round
      clcks = (clcks + 1);
      if(clcks>8)clcks=1;

                                switch (true) {
            case clcks == 1:
            alert (clcks);
                $('#txtbox6').addClass(curClass[clcks]);
                $('#txtbox6').removeClass('ordrTabl8');
                break;                  
            case clcks == 2:
                alert (clcks);
                $('#txtbox6').addClass(curClass[clcks]);
                $('#txtbox6').removeClass('ordrTabl1');
                break;
            case clcks == 3:
                alert (clcks);
                $('#txtbox6').addClass(curClass[clcks]);
                $('#txtbox6').removeClass('ordrTabl2');
                break;
            case clcks == 4:
                alert (clcks);
                $('#txtbox6').addClass('ordrTabl4');
                $('#txtbox6').removeClass('ordrTabl3');
                break; 
            case clcks == 5:
                alert (clcks);
                $('#txtbox6').addClass('ordrTabl5');
                $('#txtbox6').removeClass('ordrTabl4');
                break; 
            case clcks == 6:
                alert (clcks);
                $('#txtbox6').addClass('ordrTabl6');
                $('#txtbox6').removeClass('ordrTabl5');
                break; 
            case clcks == 7:
                alert (clcks);
                $('#txtbox6').addClass('ordrTabl7');
                $('#txtbox6').removeClass('ordrTabl6');
                break; 
            case clcks == 8:
            alert (clcks);
                $('#txtbox6').addClass('ordrTabl8');
                $('#txtbox6').removeClass('ordrTabl7');
                break; 
                                }
     

 } );

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cyclStylsArrayCntr">dfgdfgdfgdfg</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#pop7").click(function() {
    var hamPrice = 3;
    var herringPrice = 1;
    var linkPrice = 3;
    var ham = document.getElementById('ham').value;
    var herring = document.getElementById('herring').value;
    var htlnk = document.getElementById('htlnk').value;
    var divObj = document.getElementById("txtbox4");
    var hamTotal = hamPrice * ham;
    var herringTotal = herringPrice * herring;
    var linkTotal = linkPrice * htlnk;
    var grandTotal = hamTotal + herringTotal + linkTotal;
    $('.tmp9').css("background-color", "#75BDFF");
    $('.tmp9').css("height", "400px");
    $('.tmp9').css("width", "400px");
    $('.tmp9').css("box-shadow", "10px 10px 2px #333333");
    $('.tmp9').css("border", " 6px double  #660000");
    $('.tmp9').css("-webkit-border-radius", "9px");
    $('.tmp9').css("-moz-border-radius", "9px");
    $('.tmp9').css("border-radius", "9px");
    $('.tmp9').css("padding", "10px");
    $(".tmp9").toggle();
    $(".tmp9").html('<p class="tmp9"><p>' + ham + ' hams sold at $' + hamPrice + ' for  $' + hamTotal + '</p><br><p>' + herring + ' herring sold at $' + herringPrice + ' for  $' + herringTotal + '</p><br><p>' + htlnk + ' Texas hot links sold at $' + linkPrice + ' for  $' + linkTotal + '</p><br><p > For a total sale of  $' + grandTotal + '</p><br> Thank you for your business.  Please come again. </p><br>');

  });

  $("#popup7").click(function() {
    $("#detail7").toggle();
    $(window.location.href = "#top")
  });


  $('#swapStyle1').click(function(event) {
    $('#txtbox6').addClass('ordrTabl1');
    $('#txtbox6').removeClass('ordrTabl2');
    $('#txtbox6').removeClass('ordrTabl3');
  });

  $('#swapStyle2').click(function(event) {
    $('#txtbox6').addClass('ordrTabl2');
    $('#txtbox6').removeClass('ordrTabl3');
    $('#txtbox6').removeClass('ordrTabl1');
  });

  $('#swapStyle3').click(function(event) {
    $('#txtbox6').addClass('ordrTabl3');
    $('#txtbox6').removeClass('ordrTabl2');
    $('#txtbox6').removeClass('ordrTabl1');
  });

  $("#clrSaleData").click(function() {
    $('.tmp9').css("display", "none");
  });


  $('#cyclStyls').click(function(event) {
    var curClass = ['ordrTabl1', 'ordrTabl2', 'ordrTabl3']; // Array of scores
    var arrayLength = curClass.length; // Items in array
    var count = 0; // Current round
    var msg = ''; // Message

    // Loop through the items in the array
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
      $('#txtbox6').removeClass(curClass[i]);
      // Arrays are zero based (so 0 is round 1)
      // Add 1 to the current round
      count = (i + 1);
      alert(curClass[i])
      $('#txtbox6').addClass(curClass[i]);
    }

  });


  var cliks = 1;

  function cyclStylsSwtch() {

    if (cliks < 3) {
      cliks += 1;
    } else {
      alert('else statement')
      cliks = 1;
    }
    switch (true) {
      case cliks == 1:
        $('#txtbox6').addClass('ordrTabl1');
        $('#txtbox6').removeClass('ordrTabl3');
        break;
      case cliks == 2:
        $('#txtbox6').addClass('ordrTabl2');
        $('#txtbox6').removeClass('ordrTabl1');
        break;
      case cliks == 3:
        $('#txtbox6').addClass('ordrTabl3');
        $('#txtbox6').removeClass('ordrTabl2');
        break;
      case cliks == 4:
        cliks = 1;
        alert(cliks);
        break;
      case cliks == 5:
        cliks = 1;
        alert(cliks);
        break;
    }

  };

  var clix = 1;

  $("#cyclStylsSwtch").click(function() {

    if (clix < 8) {
      clix += 1;
    } else {
      clix = 1;
    }
    switch (true) {
      case clix == 1:
        $('#txtbox6').addClass('ordrTabl1');
        $('#txtbox6').removeClass('ordrTabl8');
        break;
      case clix == 2:
        $('#txtbox6').removeClass('ordrTabl1');
        $('#txtbox6').addClass('ordrTabl2');

        break;
      case clix == 3:
        $('#txtbox6').addClass('ordrTabl3');
        $('#txtbox6').removeClass('ordrTabl2');
        break;
      case clix == 4:
        $('#txtbox6').addClass('ordrTabl4');
        $('#txtbox6').removeClass('ordrTabl3');
        break;
      case clix == 5:
        $('#txtbox6').addClass('ordrTabl5');
        $('#txtbox6').removeClass('ordrTabl4');
        break;
      case clix == 6:
        $('#txtbox6').addClass('ordrTabl6');
        $('#txtbox6').removeClass('ordrTabl5');
        break;
      case clix == 7:
        $('#txtbox6').addClass('ordrTabl7');
        $('#txtbox6').removeClass('ordrTabl6');
        break;
      case clix == 8:
        $('#txtbox6').addClass('ordrTabl8');
        $('#txtbox6').removeClass('ordrTabl7');
        break;
    }



  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you.  Removing the for loop worked.    I dropped this code in and it steps through relatively cleanly.  I'll need to fiddle with the logic a bit  to get a clean first and last entry (need to click twice now).

Comment: here is a copy of the working file on one of my sites To be fiddled with in Perpetuity:                   http://etherealdoorways.com/ordrEntryFrmFlxStyling.html

Comment: try the above script and your double click problem will be solved

Comment: and don't use too many `$(document).ready(function() {` and also do marked the answer as accepted if you problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the for loop and use the clcks to get the classes.
Check if this works (pardon any missing brackets):

```
 $('#cyclStylsArrayCntr').click(function(event){
    var curClass = ['ordrTabl1', 'ordrTabl2', 'ordrTabl3', 'ordrTabl4',  'ordrTabl5', 'ordrTabl6', 'ordrTabl7', 'ordrTabl8'];      
 // Array of scores
    var arrayLength = curClass.length;// Items in array
    var clcks = 0;            // Current round
    var msg = '';                   // Message

  if (clcks < 8){

                    clcks+=1;

                        }
                            else{

                            clcks = 1;

                        };

      // Arrays are zero based (so 0 is round 1)
      // Add 1 to the current round


                                switch (true) {
            case clcks == 1:
            alert (clcks);
                $('#txtbox6').addClass(curClass[clcks-1]);
                $('#txtbox6').removeClass(curClass[7]);
                break;                  
            case clcks == 2:
                $('#txtbox6').addClass(curClass[clcks-1]);
                $('#txtbox6').removeClass(curClass[clcks-2]);
                break;
            case clcks == 3:
                $('#txtbox6').addClass(curClass[clcks-1]);
                $('#txtbox6').removeClass(curClass[clcks-2]);
                break;
            case clcks == 4:
                $('#txtbox6').addClass(curClass[clcks-1]);
                $('#txtbox6').removeClass(curClass[clcks-2]);
                break; 
            case clcks == 5:
                $('#txtbox6').addClass(curClass[clcks-1]);
                $('#txtbox6').removeClass(curClass[clcks-2]);
                break; 
            case clcks == 6:
                $('#txtbox6').addClass(curClass[clcks-1]);
                $('#txtbox6').removeClass(curClass[clcks-2]);
                break; 
            case clcks == 7:
                $('#txtbox6').addClass(curClass[clcks-1]);
                $('#txtbox6').removeClass(curClass[clcks-2]);
                break; 
            case clcks == 8:
            alert (clcks);
                $('#txtbox6').addClass(curClass[clcks-1]);
                $('#txtbox6').removeClass(curClass[clcks-2]);
                break; 
                                }

 } );

    }); 

 </script>
```